# IBM MobileFirst iOS client cannot register/recieve token

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I am executing the sample **iOS** Application downloaded from the operations console in **IBM MobileFirst**.

When it comes to click the button and to trigger a request for the token from the server, I get the **Application does not exist** error:

```
2017-10-23 15:17:52.671942+0200 MFPStarterIOSSwift[10038:1206818] WL_REQUEST
Did not receive an access token from server: Optional(Error Domain=WL_AUTH Code=403 "Application doesn't exist" UserInfo={networkMetadata={
    "$bytesSent" = 652;
    "$category" = network;
    "$outboundTimestamp" = 1508764672641;
    "$path" = "http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/registration/v1/self";
    "$requestMethod" = POST;
    "$trackingid" = "7FEFBF12-0766-4427-920E-30E6BA3314DA";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=Application doesn't exist})
```

My server is running and I can successfully connect to it via android emulator. But the Xcode iPhone emulator returns the above-mentioned error.

For the mfpclient.plist settings I have entered:

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>protocol</key>
    <string>http</string>
    <key>host</key>
    <string>localhost</string>
    <key>port</key>
    <string>9080</string>
    <key>wlServerContext</key>
    <string>/mfp/</string>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

The **MobileFirst** server is running on the same machine as where **Xcode** and the emulators are running...

Comment: Have you registered your iOs application with the MFP server?

Comment: What do you mean by register? Setting up Confidential Client? I thought that is not necessary when you have mobile apps as clients

Comment: You still have to register an app from the MobileFirst console or CLI

Comment: Yes I have done that already. In the operations console I create a new iOS application with version "1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is not registered in MFP Operations Console and that causing `Application doesn't exist` failure in Client application.

In order to resolve the issue, Register your application by following steps mentioned [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/ios/#registering-the-application).

Comment: I had the wrong Bundle ID on MFP Operations Console. Now I copied it from the xcode project and now its working. Thank You!